# Embeding a PDF in a PDF (PDF Inception :])

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation

I'm generating a list of people in a PDF. In the first couple pages, it shows basic data in a table format.  However, if someone clicks a hyperlink, I'd like to show more detail.  Originally, I was thinking this could create an action that opens a person detail page in a new window.

I'm trying to avoid printing all person details. For instance, I could generate a person detail page for all people, then link the summary data to the detail.  However, if someone goes to print the job would likely take 300 pages.

Is there a way to open a new PDF through embeding a hidden PDF in a PDF, or is there a way to hide pages from being printed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can embed the person details as file attachments. A PDF file can include file attachments and there attachments can be PDF files.
PDF 1.6 supports the GoTo Embedded action, when you click on a link you can go to a destination in an embedded file.
How a PDF viewer implements the actual navigation in such scenario (between master and detail) remains to be tested.

Answer (score 1):

PDF files can contain hidden, named, pages called "templates". Template pages can then be hidden or shown via JavaScript (in a link for example).

Only pages that are showing will print.

I'm not sure how you're creating your PDF but once you have all of the pages in a single PDF, you can use JavaScript in Acrobat to create and hide a template page using something like the code below. PDF page numbers are zero based.

```
var t = this.createTemplate({cName:"MyTemplateName", nPage:0 });
t.hidden = true;
```

Then you'd add links that execute JavaScript to show a particular template or set of templates like this...

```
this.getTemplate("MyTemplateName").hidden = false;
```

By default, template pages that go from hidden to visible get appended to the end of the document.

Comment: What library would you use to achieve this?  Currently, the old PDF is generated by Crystal. Are you recommending a HTML/JS approach i.e. PhantomJS?

Comment: What library would you use to achieve this? Currently, the old PDF is generated by Crystal. Are you recommending a HTML/JS approach i.e. PhantomJS? @joelgeraci

Comment: Just about any decent PDF library will let you create template pages and add JavaScript to links even if you have to go down to the COS level to do it. But you'll likely be post processing the file. I don't know of any PDF creation software that will create template pages as the PDF is being generated.

Comment: So, if I was to continue using Crystal, I could generate the report. The post process that file to add templates? @joelgeraci

Comment: Exactly... but to be more precise, you'd post process the file to turn normal pages into template pages and hide them. You could do this in Acrobat Pro DC as an action or use a library tool.